# Slow wi-fi speed Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, ethernet, acer

Have a problem with slow internet connection by Wi-Fi. Using Acer aspire e5-575g. On windows 10 speed is ok. Tried a lot of stuff from google, but nothing changed.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [this link](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex). If the download by the first link failed, download [this file](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).
2. Open the terminal and run these commands you ubuntu pc.

   ```
   cd rtlwifi_new-master
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
   sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
   sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up
   sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan
   ```